# Which strings are empty?

Tags: java, string, special-characters, is-empty

In the JDK documentation it states that the String method `isEmpty()` is true for any string of length 0.

This is obviously true for the empty string `""`.

Are there any other string for which this is the case? I have tested line breaks and carriage returns and they have a length. I have not yet tested characters with appended backspaces.

---

Edit: I appreciate all the additional information in all the good answers below, however I have accepted what I believe is the most direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A "string of length zero" means that the string contains no characters at all, and that includes invisible, zero-width, etc. Unicode characters.

Therefore a string whose on-screen representation is completely blank and zero-width is still non-empty if it contains a character.

Answer (score 8):

A String of length 0 contains 0 characters. So no, there are no other Strings that would be empty except for the empty String.

Answer (score 4):

See the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java) of it:

```
670     public boolean isEmpty() {
671         return count == 0;
672     }
```

Where `count` is the number of characters in the String.

That will be the case only if there are no characters in the String, which is only `""`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two usefull methods in apaches commons [org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class

`isBlank(CharSequence cs)`

Checks if a CharSequence is whitespace, empty ("") or null.

`isEmpty(CharSequence cs)`

Checks if a CharSequence is empty ("") or null.

Maybe this is, what you're looking for, if you didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

From Java 1.6 onwords [`String.isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) is available to use. It is faster than `String.equals("")` call. Strings store a count variable initialized in the constructor, since Strings are immutable.

`isEmpty()` compares the count variable to 0, while equals will check the type, string length, and then iterate over the string for comparison if the sizes match.

from javadoc-

```
public boolean isEmpty()
Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.
Returns:
true if length() is 0, otherwise false
Since:
1.6
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29)

> `String#isEmpty()` Returns `true` if, and only if, [`length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29%60) is
>   0.

So, there are no other cases where `isEmpty()` will return `true`